classicmenu-indicator fails to run
Running on Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble Numbat) I get the following error:
$ classicmenu-indicator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/classicmenu-indicator", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('classicmenu-indicator==0.11', 'console_scripts', 'classicmenu-indicator')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/classicmenu_indicator/cmindicator.py", line 578, in main
    indicator = ClassicMenuIndicator()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/classicmenu_indicator/cmindicator.py", line 152, in __init__
    gettext.bind_textdomain_codeset(settings.GETTEXT_DOMAIN, 'UTF-8')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'gettext' has no attribute 'bind_textdomain_codeset'

My python version is :
$ python3
Python 3.12.3

I had the same issue. Resolved by unmarking line 152 on "usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/classicmenu_indicator/cmindicator.py"
Using Ubuntu 24.04

@user1923837 You said "Can you please give me exact commands to "unmarking line 152" and saving it, and how to run the modified version.". Using your preferred editor (I use vi) 'sudo vi  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/classicmenu_indicator/cmindicator.py' Go to line 152 (vi = :152) Then insert a '#' at the beginning of the line. Save and exit (vi = :wq). I think you then just run it again. (If memory serves python is interpretive rather than compiled.)
